# ¿Cómo romper bucles for anidados en C?

Tags: c, bucle-for, bucles

tengo un problema, estoy realizando un temporizador para que al momento de que se cumpla el tiempo ingresado por el usuario todos los ciclos for rompan pero no me sale con un brake, alguien me podría dar una opción para hacerlo?

**Quiero que al momento de que se cumpla la condición de en medio se rompa todo el ciclo**

´´´
int EntradaMilisegundos, EntradaSegundos, EntradaMinutos;
int milisegundos, segundos, minutos;

```
printf("\t*Ingresa el tiempo*");
printf("\n*Minutos: ");
scanf("%i", &EntradaMinutos);
printf("\n*Segundos: ");
scanf("%i", &EntradaSegundos);
printf("\n*Milisegundos: ");
scanf("%i", &EntradaMilisegundos);

printf("Tiempo establecido %d%s%d%s%d%s",EntradaMinutos,":",EntradaSegundos,":",EntradaMilisegundos);


for(minutos=0;minutos<60;minutos++) {
    for (segundos = 0; segundos < 60; segundos++) {
        for (milisegundos = 0; milisegundos < 1000; milisegundos++) {
            printf("\nTiempo: %d%s%d%s%d", minutos,":",segundos,":",milisegundos);
            if(EntradaMinutos == minutos && EntradaSegundos == segundos && EntradaMilisegundos == milisegundos){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}´´´
```

Comment: Puedes escribirlo como `printf("\nTiempo: %d:%d:%d", minutos, segundos, milisegundos)`. Por cierto, los procesadores actuales pueden ejecutar más de un millón de instrucciones por segundo. Por lo que el temporizador terminará antes de lo previsto.

Answer (score 0):

Las variables "minutos", "segundos" y "milisegundos" deben estar declaradas antes de los bucles, y son solo variables auxiliares para el for, debes usar estas y las que recibis del usuario para declarar los for, fijate que son diferentes a como los hiciste. Y la comparacion debe ser <= no < porque sino te muestra el numero buscado - 1. Despues el break estaba bien puesto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int EntradaMinutos, EntradaSegundos, EntradaMilisegundos;

    printf("\t*Ingresa el tiempo*");
    printf("\n*Minutos: ");
    scanf("%i", &EntradaMinutos);
    printf("\n*Segundos: ");
    scanf("%i", &EntradaSegundos);
    printf("\n*Milisegundos: ");
    scanf("%i", &EntradaMilisegundos);

    printf("Tiempo establecido %d%s%d%s%d%s",EntradaMinutos,":",EntradaSegundos,":",EntradaMilisegundos);

    int minutos, segundos, milisegundos;

    for(minutos = 0;minutos <=EntradaMinutos ;minutos++) {
        for (segundos = 0; segundos <= EntradaSegundos; segundos++) {
            for (milisegundos = 0; milisegundos <= EntradaMilisegundos; milisegundos++) {
                printf("\nTiempo: %d%s%d%s%d", minutos,":",segundos,":",milisegundos);
                if(EntradaMinutos == minutos && EntradaSegundos == segundos && EntradaMilisegundos == milisegundos){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tene en cuenta que al poner un numero alto de milisegundos (mayor a 1000) el programa va a tardar un poco y mientras mas mayor sea el valor en milisegundos mas va a tardar en mostrar el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

`break` solo rompe un ciclo.

Puedes salir de los ciclos haciendo que sus condiciones no se cumplan. Por ejemplo:

```
for (minutos=0; minutos < 60; minutos++) {
    for (segundos = 0; segundos < 60; segundos++) {
        for (milisegundos = 0; milisegundos < 1000; milisegundos++) {
            printf("\nTiempo: %d%s%d%s%d", minutos,":",segundos,":",milisegundos);
            if(EntradaMinutos == minutos && EntradaSegundos == segundos && EntradaMilisegundos == milisegundos){
                minutos = segundos = 60;
                milisegundos = 1000;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes mover los ciclos a otra función y reemplazar `break` por `return` para romperlos todos. O si no hay código luego, no es necesario que los muevas.

Otra opción es usar `goto`. Colocas una etiqueta donde quieres que el código vaya y lo usas así:

```
for (minutos=0; minutos < 60; minutos++) {
    for (segundos = 0; segundos < 60; segundos++) {
        for (milisegundos = 0; milisegundos < 1000; milisegundos++) {
            printf("\nTiempo: %d%s%d%s%d", minutos,":",segundos,":",milisegundos);
            if(EntradaMinutos == minutos && EntradaSegundos == segundos && EntradaMilisegundos == milisegundos){
                goto fuera;
            }
        }
    }
}

fuera:

// Más código
```

Basado en las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9695902/13419694).